# Python print value in a defined number of textboxs based on row count

Tags: python-3.x

i have a db table with a Column1=Name and Column2= attributes. For each Name, the max number of attribute values = 5. In my GUI (generated through python), i have 5 textboxes that according to the select statement i print the attribute value. I try to insert into the row_count statement the print result but i can't find a solution, i don't know how to use as a parameter the row_count, meaning that if the row_count=3 then print 3 results (in order to put it in the first three textboxes), if 1 then 1 result etc, if rowcount-1<0, continue with the rest code without filling the rest textboxes. I isolated below only the select part. Thanks in advance.

```
     import cx_Oracle
     connstr='SOLVATIO/SOLVATIO@localhost'
     conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connstr)
     curs = conn.cursor()
     curs.execute("select attributes, count(*) from customer_desc group     by attributes")      
     result=curs.fetchall()
     r_count=curs.rowcount
     print("number of:{}".format(r_count))
     if r_count==0:
     print("no rows")
     else:
       print(result[???])->based on r_count i.e if r_count=3, print(result[0]),print(result[1]), print(result[2])
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Probably my approach is wrong and i should insert the query results into a dataset that will fill each textbox according to rowcount ? meaning that i must relate dataset results with textboxes, in a parametric way? any hints?

Answer (score 0):

```
     import cx_Oracle
     from tkinter import*
     from tkinter import messagebox

     def search():
     try:

     connstr='SOLVATIO/SOLVATIO@localhost'
     conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connstr)
     curs = conn.cursor()
     curs1= conn.cursor()
     curs.execute("select * from customers where afm='%s'"%afm.get())      
     result=curs.fetchone()
     company_name.set(result[1])
     siebel_customer_code.set(result[3])
     #2nd fetch#
     curs1.execute("select name_project,description, count(*) from customer_desc where company_name_d='%s' group by name_project, description"%e2.get())
     results=curs1.fetchall()
     r_count=curs.rowcount
     #print("number of:{}".format(r_count))
     if r_count==0:
      print("no rows")
     else:
      for i in range (0, r_count):
       if i==0:
        name_project.set(results[0][0])
        description.set(results[0][1])
       elif i==1:
        name_project.set(results[1][0])
        description.set(results[1][1])
       elif i==2:
        name_project.set(results[2][0])
        description.set(results[2][1])
       elif i==3:
        name_project.set(results[3][0])
        description.set(results[3][1])
       else:
        name_project.set(results[4][0])
        description.set(results[4][1])      
    e1.configure(state='disabled')
    # f1.configure(state='disabled')
    conn.close()

    except:
    messagebox.showinfo('No data', 'No such data')

    def clear():
    afm.set('')
    company_name.set('')
    siebel_customer_code.set('')
    name_project.set('')
    description.set('')
    e1.configure(state='normal')
    f1.configure(state='normal')

    w1=Tk()
    w1.title('GUI Special Solutions')
    w1.geometry('1350x750+0+0')
    ptitle=Label(w1, font=('arial',11,'bold'),text='''Search Asset''')
    ptitle.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

    afm=StringVar()
    company_name=StringVar()
    siebel_customer_code=StringVar()
    name_project=StringVar()
    description=StringVar()

    l1=Label (w1, text=' AFM ')
    e1=Entry(w1, textvariable=afm)
    l2=Label (w1, text=' Πελάτης ')
    e2=Entry(w1, textvariable=company_name)
    l3=Label (w1, text=' Siebel Code ')
    e3=Entry(w1, textvariable=siebel_customer_code)
    b1=Button(w1, text=' Search ', command=search)
    b2=Button(w1, text=' Clear ', command=clear)
    l4=Label (w1, text=' Όνομα Έργου ')
    f1=Entry(w1, textvariable=name_project)
    l5=Label (w1, text=' Περιγραφή Έργου ')
    f2=Entry(w1, textvariable=description, fg="lime green", bd=4, width=140)

    f3=Entry(w1, textvariable=name_project)
    f4=Entry(w1, textvariable=description, fg="lime green", bd=4, width=140)
    f5=Entry(w1, textvariable=name_project)
    f6=Entry(w1, textvariable=description, fg="lime green", bd=4, width=140)
    f7=Entry(w1, textvariable=name_project)
    f8=Entry(w1, textvariable=description, fg="lime green", bd=4, width=140)
    f9=Entry(w1, textvariable=name_project)
    f10=Entry(w1, textvariable=description, fg="lime green", bd=4, width=140)


    l1.grid(row=1, column=0)
    e1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    l2.grid(row=2, column=0)
    e2.grid(row=2, column=1)
    l3.grid(row=3, column=0)
    e3.grid(row=3, column=1)
    b1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    b2.grid(row=4, column=0)
    l4.grid(row=5, column=0)
    f1.grid(row=5, column=1)
    l5.grid(row=5, column=2)
    f2.grid(row=5, column=3)

    f3.grid(row=6, column=1)
    f4.grid(row=6, column=3)
    f5.grid(row=7, column=1)
    f6.grid(row=7, column=3)
    f7.grid(row=8, column=1)
    f8.grid(row=8, column=3)
    f9.grid(row=9, column=1)
    f10.grid(row=9, column=3)

    w1.mainloop()
```